# Convert private attributes into dict

Tags: python

supposed that I've had one class with private attributes such the example below:

```
class AwesomeClass:
   def __init__(self):
      self._var = 1
      self._awesome = 'awesome'
```

When I call `vars(AwesomeClass)` the return value is:

```
{'_var': 1, '_awesome': 'awesome'}
```

So I'm missing something to get the correct value without the private initiator? How can I return my correct dict without underscore value? Such as the example below?

```
{'var': 1, 'awesome': 'awesome'}
```

Comment: Those aren't private attributes. There's nothing special about attributes that begin with a single `_`, it's just a naming convention. Private attributes begin with two underscores, and they're translated to `_<classname>__<attributename>`.

Comment: There's nothing that will automatically remove the `_`.

Comment: So the correct way to achieve what I want is to overload the `getattr`? Or the `getitem?`

Comment: And what is the more elegant way to make this conversion?

Comment: @Barmar double leading underscores isn't private either, a single underscore is the convetion for "private" anyway

Comment: @JoãoMazagão no. What do you think `vars` does? It returns the *namespace of the instnace*, why **wouldn't** it return the names? this `{'_var': 1, '_awesome': 'awesome'}` is the *correct return value*

Comment: why do you need to have `_` leading var names in any case?

Comment: note that the result you're seeing above is actually the correct output in this case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's private in the sense that you can't access them from outside the class without doing the transformation yourself.

Comment: Why do you need the dict? If you want a function that creates a dict from the underscore attributes, write it.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I have some logic rules to build my class in some logic that the default value is no passing. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Barmar that sounds good to me, but I'm keeping thinking that I'm not using correctly the python interface. And for that i've looking for something "native" to do that.

Comment: There's no Python interface for this. There's nothing that assumes a correspondence between `_var` and `var`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, so the approach is to create a parser function to transform into a `dict`.

Comment: Attributes like `_var` are often used to hold the data underlying the property named `var`. But there's nothing built-in that implements this, it's just a common naming convention.

Comment: Again, it is really important to understand, `vars(my_object)` doesn't *create a dict out of an object*, it **returns the object's namespace**. You almost certainly don't want that in this case, because if you *mutate that dict*, it *mutates the object's namespace* (because the `dict` *is* the namespace). At the very least, you probably want `vars(my_object).copy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you get from `vars(...)` is correct, because you named the variable with a leading underscore.

So if you want to have the names without the leading underscore, you could transform the dictionary keys like this:

```
{key.lstrip('_'): val for key, val in vars(AwesomeClass).items()}
```